# How to find the count of values for each key in a linked hashmap where the key and value are words

Tags: java

```
for(String j1:word1.keySet())
{
    System.out.println(j1+"\t"+word1.get(j1));
}
```

This code gives the count of all words in the hashmap. I have the input as:

```
movie good  
song bad  
music good   
movie super
```

How do I find the count of the words related to each key?

It should produce the result:

```
movie 2  
song 1  
music 1  
good 2  
bad 1  
super 1
```

Comment: What type is word1 and how is it initialized?

Comment: Please consider rephrasing your question, since it's hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> word1

Comment: create another key value pair where key is the word and value is the number of occurrence of each word. Search for no. of occurrence of each word if it doesnot exists in new key value pair. Just somewhat like counting sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to print the total count of all the `Strings` appeared in the `LinkedHashMap`

```
public class Test {

    //using a HashMap to keep count of all the words
    private static Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> words1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        words1.put("a", "movie good");
        words1.put("b", "song bad");
        words1.put("c", "music good");
        words1.put("d", "movie super");
        countWords(words1);

    }


    public static void countWords(LinkedHashMap word1){
        Set keys = word1.keySet();
        Iterator itr = keys.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()){
            String value = (String) word1.get(itr.next());
            String[] valueArray = value.split(" ");
            for(String s:valueArray){
                Integer count = countMap.get(s);
                if(count != null){
                    countMap.put(s, ++count);
                }else{
                    countMap.put(s, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        //print the final count of all the words
        for(Entry<String, Integer> entrySet: countMap.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(entrySet.getKey() + " " + entrySet.getValue());
        }

    }
}
```